# Как сделать такую выборку sql по датам?

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю афишу(модуль dle 13) для сайта надо сделать выборку 
Есть таблица с полем(дат формата Y-m-d) xfields по которому надо сделать выборку, надо выбрать новости в диапазон дат которых входит текущая дата + 14 дней

```
Пример поля xfields  date|2018-10-16 2018-10-17 2018-10-18 2018-10-19 2018-10-20 2018-10-21 2018-10-22 2018-10-23 2018-10-24 2018-10-25 2018-10-26 2018-10-27 2018-10-28 2018-10-30 2018-10-29 2018-10-31
```

Comment: Поле в таблице какого типа? `DATE` или `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Mediumtext тип у поля

Comment: И зачем это было сделано?

Comment: Так как в данном поле может храниться разная информация от текста до дат и html кода вот пример с другого сайта того же поля    date_from|2018-11-17||date_to|2018-11-17||poster|2018-10/1539767114_nurg0v5y6_o.jpg

Comment: И как вы собираетесь выбирать данные на основании поля с произвольным форматом?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  xfields BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAYS)
```